# Scraping iframe data using Nokogiri and Ruby

Tags: ruby, iframe, nokogiri, scrape

This is my script written to scrape data inside the `<iframe>` tag using Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'restclient'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get("http://www.sample_site.com/")) 
doc.xpath('//iframe[@width="1001" and @height="973"]').children
```

I am getting like this:

```
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1913970 "\r\nYour browser does not support inline frames\r\n">]
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

**An  `iframe` is used to embed another document within the current HTML document**. It means the iframe loads his content from an external source that is specified in the `src` attribute.

So, if you want to do scraping to an `iframe` content you should send a request to the external source from where it loads his content.

```
# The iframe (notice the 'src' attribute)
<iframe src="iframe_source_url" height="973" width="1001">
  # iframe content
</iframe>

# Code to do the scraping
doc = RestClient.get('iframe_source_url')
parsed_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(doc) 
parsed_doc.css('#yourSelectorHere') # or parsed_doc.xpath('...')
```

**Note (about the error)**

When you do scraping, the HTTP client you use acts as your browser (yours is `restclient`). The error says your browser does not support inline frames, in other words, `restclient` does not support inline-frames and is why it cannot load the content of the frame.

Comment: I suspect the text response is the result of an embedded string that literally says "Your browser does not support inline frames" in the HTML. It's not dynamically generated because of the client, it's always there and when a browser that does support iframes loads the page that's hidden by the content.

Comment: I'm not saying it is dynamically generated by the client, just that restclient does not support iframes, so it can not load the content. But thaks  for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is to be addressed to `RestClient`, not to `Nokogiri`.

`RestClient` does not retrieve the content of `iframe`s. You might want to try to examine the content of `RestClient.get("http://www.sample_site.com/")`, there will be the string like:

```
<iframe src="page-1.htm" name="test" height="120" width="600">
  You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.
</iframe>
```

`Nokogiri` is fine dealing with this, it returns the content of `iframe` node which is apparently the only `TextNode` having the string you yielded as a result.